# "Arithmetic Overflow" Exception when generating a PDF with PuppeteerSharp, for a very large webpage

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

We are getting the following exception when attempting to generate a PDF for a very large webpage with PuppeteerSharp. I have duplicated this with versions 2.0.3, 2.04 & 4.0 of PuppeteerSharp.

**Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.ProtocolStreamReader.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Helpers\ProtocolStreamReader.cs:line 83
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at PuppeteerSharp.Page.d__171.MoveNext() in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Page.cs:line 1003
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

Comment: Can you reproduce that with a public site or an static HTML page?

Comment: We generate the web page on-the-fly in a forms application so the webpage isn't persisted on its own. This error occurs with very very large pages with lots of large images. We are working on duplicating this issue with smaller images, but in the meantime, I can provide a zip file with the HTML and other files of the one we have now, but it is huge. What would be the best way to transfer that to you?

Comment: Please create an issue with an example and I'll take a look at it.